# jquery issue with click when firering .on

Tags: jquery, click, live

I need to know what is going wrong here, when I try to run the following it does not work, not alert box no error nothing.

```
$(function() { 
$("tbody[name=leadstores]").on("click","tr",function(e){

alert("clicked");
});

});
```

Just wondering am I doing something wrong.

Forgot to say, that this script was working when I used

> .live

here is the table

```
<table id="tableprod" style="width: 100%; ">
<thead id="storelocation" class="fixedHeader" style="min-width: 800px; ">
<tbody id="tbbody" name="leadstores">

<tr id="20">
<td name="street" class="company" style="width: 400px; padding-right: 2%; ">Shop 1012, Westfield Bondi Junction, 500 Oxford Street</td>
<td name="suburb" class="company" style="padding-right: 3%; ">Bondi Junction</td>
<td name="postcode" class="field" style="padding-right: 3%; ">2022</td>
<td name="state" class="field" style="padding-right: 3%; ">NSW</td>
<td name="phone" class="company">(02) 9388</td>
</tr>
<tr id="21">
<td name="street" class="company" style="width: 400px; padding-right: 2%; ">Kiosk KG17, Westfield Doncaster, 619 Doncaster Road</td>
<td name="suburb" class="company" style="padding-right: 3%; ">Doncaster</td>
<td name="postcode" class="field" style="padding-right: 3%; ">3108</td>
<td name="state" class="field" style="padding-right: 3%; ">VIC</td>
<td name="phone" class="company">(03) 9840</td>
</tr>
<tr id="23">
<td name="street" class="company" style="width: 400px; padding-right: 2%; ">Kiosk 66A, Macquarie Centre, cnr Herring & Waterloo Rd</td>
<td name="suburb" class="company" style="padding-right: 3%; ">North Ryde</td>
<td name="postcode" class="field" style="padding-right: 3%; ">2113</td>
<td name="state" class="field" style="padding-right: 3%; ">NSW</td>
<td name="phone" class="company">(02) 9889</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That would depend on your HTML.

Comment: check your error console. May be some other script error

Comment: The key to answering your question lies in you posting your HTML as SLaks already told you.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mQSrx/

Comment: Works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/3nnez/ (cut and pasted directly)

Comment: I think the reason that works, is because that info is there in the table already, where in mine the page is ajax so it is not there and needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **.live()** can be the problem solver

when your targeting DOM ( **tbody[name=leadstores] in your case** )

is added dynamically after the page loaded.

.live() listens on newly added DOM so that you can bind events with those

dynamically added DOM.

**EDIT:**

Since .live() is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.x,

```
$("#tableprod").on("click","tr",function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Try this

Comment: but jQuery is dropping .live for .on so we need to also move forward

Comment: hmm i see    .live() is deprecated since 1.7.x

Answer (score 0):

Your table element must have a tbody element with name="leadstores" for your js to work:

```
<table>
<tbody name="leadstores">
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your table added to the DOM dynamically? I.e. does it already exist in the page when the page loads? If it does not, then on() will not work. From on() method description: **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().** 
If you want to use on() method, you will need to apply it to an element that already exists on the page, like 'body' for example: $("body").on("click","tbody[name='leadstores'] tr",function(e){alert("clicked");});